# Executar coisas rápidas sincronamente e coisas demoradas assincronamente?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, async, assincronismo

Geralmente, em .NET, executo coisas **demoradas** de forma assíncrona para não travar a *thread* visual. Num exemplo simples, se tenho um *loading* na UI, caso coisas demoradas sejam executadas sem que *awaitadas*, elas travam esse *loading*, que foi executado na *thread* visual.

Ações que eventualmente possam ser demoradas, como processar uma lista, *loops* ou leitura de arquivos, eu executo assincronamente. Mas quando tenho coisas que sei que não são demoradas, como uma estrutura condicional simples:

```
public bool? ToBoolean(int input)
{
    if (input == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (input == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Para estes casos, que sei que são rápidos (em tese), eu deveria ter algo do tipo?

```
public async Task<bool?> ToBooleanAsync(int input)
{
  return await Task.Run(() => ToBoolean(input));
}
```

Devo executar coisas rápidas de forma assíncrona, e por que (ou por que não)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, de maneira alguma deve fazer isto. Neste caso específico armar e controlar toda infraestrutura da assincronicidade levará absurdamente mais tempo que a execução deste método.

A recomendação para a chamada assíncrona compensar é o método levar 50 milissegundos (na máquina do usuário, não na sua poderosa de desenvolvedor). Inclusive porque um tempo menor que este nem é muito percebido pelo humano, e fazer algo assíncrono serve apenas para melhorar a experiência do usuário. Ele não executa melhor ou mais rápido. Pelo contrário, é até mais lento.

Se aquilo roda em servidor, em *batch*, fora da interação com usuário a assincronicidade não ajuda da mesma forma. Aí depende se solução desenvolvida tem uma fila única de execução ou pode haver execuções independentes, quem sabe até a assincronicidade seja usada para permitir mais de uma linha de execução, não uma regra clara, tem que medir. Certamente algo tão simples assim não compensa. Muitas vezes só vai compensar para tempos bem mais altos.

Comment: Como monto tal estrutura? Posso criar outra pergunta

Comment: Você não monta, isso é interno, o compilador gera uma parte, as bibliotecas fazem outra.